# How to bind a text box change event exactly when a number is entered?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to loop through the cells of a 9 * 9 Sudoku grid. When a digit from 1 - 9 has been entered in the text boxes, I just want to alert.

```
        $('table tr td input').on({"change": function () {
                var cell = $(this).val();
                alert("Cell Value = " + cell);
        }});
```

The above code alerts only when the user takes the cursor out of the text box. But I want it to be as soon as he enters. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `input` method as event:

```
$('table tr td input').on({"input": function () {
```

---

As per your comments you have to use `keyup` event then because `input` event doesn't give you the keycode access:

```
$('input').on({
   "keyup": function (e) {
      var cell = $(this).val(),
          kc = e.which || e.keyCode; // get the keycode
      if (kc !== 8 && kc !== 46) { // alert only if not backspace and delete
          alert("Cell Value = " + cell);
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Yes: it's better than keyup, because it will also work if something is pasted into the box using the mouse.

Comment: @MauricePerry absolutely.

Comment: @Jai The cell Value is alerted on even when the number is removed from the text box. But how to avoid it?

Comment: @MauricePerry The cell Value is alerted on even when the number is removed from the text box. But how to avoid it?

Comment: @user3627139 not getting you, does this mean you need to make it disable when number getting removed. i mean plz explain little bit more...

Comment: avoid what? can't you just ignore it?

Comment: @Jai I want an alert message to be triggered when the user enters a number. But when he removes there should be no alert. I want this feature to be used to alert the user while there are duplicates. But when he removes number there is no need to inform him.

Comment: @user3627139 have a look at the updated code you have to move to `keyup` event then.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `keyup` event in this context,

```
$('table tr td input').on({"keyup": function () {
```

### [Procedural Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Qbdd/)

Comment: @MauricePerry i could not get you.. :)

Comment: Event "input" instead of "keyup"?

Comment: @MauricePerry yeah, we can use `input` event too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use key up event to get the value

```
$('table tr td input').on({"keyup": function () {
                var cell = $(this).val();
                alert("Cell Value = " + cell);
        }});
```